# Estimating the execution time of code on local linux system

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, gcc

I spend most of my time solving problems on Topcoder/SPOJ. So definitely I thought of performance (execution time) of my code on my system before submitting the code.

So,  on searching I found `time` command in linux. But the problem is that it also includes the time for inputting the values for several test cases, in addition to processing time. So I thought of making an input file and sending that content to my code.

Something like

`cat input.txt > ./myprogram`

But this doesn't work. (I am not good at linux pipelining). Can anyone point out the mistake, or a better approach to judge my code execution time?

**EDIT**
All of my programs read from `stdin`

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Does your program read from stdin?

Comment: Read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) in addition of [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html); you could have inside your program some time measurements (e.g. you may try to measure with [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) the milliseconds it take to run some given loop).

Comment: The `>` redirects output to a file, not a program's stdin, so that overwrites `./myprogram` rather than pipes it input. The `<` in the same position redirects input from a file. So `./myprogram < input.txt` should work. The way you format your command you actually want to pipe the output of `cat` to the input of `./myprogram` - so try `cat input.text | ./myprogram`

Comment: `time` will report you (among other) the user CPU time of program run. Time spent for waiting for input will not be included in this number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this:

```
./myprogram < input.txt
```

Or if you insist on the Useless Use of Cat:

```
cat input.txt | ./myprogram
```

You can put `time` in front of `./myprogram` in either case.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. But one ques, why putting `time` in second case displays different information, though we are doing same thing in both the commands.

Comment: @InsaneCoder: `time` is a Bash builtin, but also a program `/usr/bin/time`.  Unfortunately the two things have different behavior, though they do somewhat similar tasks.  You can always use the program one by explicitly typing `/usr/bin/time`, but it's trickier to use the Bash builtin when it doesn't come on the front of the command line.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at xargs.

Something along the lines of

```
cat input.txt | xargs ./myprogram
```

Comment: `xargs` is unnecessary here; `./myprogram` isn't taking any arguments. What sort of benefit do you expect it to provide?

Answer (score -1):

You can add below code in your script for

## assign the file descriptor to file for input and output fd # 3 is

Input file
exec 3< input.txt

## Use read command in while loop to read the file line by line

while read -u 3 -r a
do